# Making a discord bot kick a certain member on typing (Python)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make my discord bot kick someone if they start typing and was wondering if it's possible. Or if a certain user sends a message at all. Was wondering if this is possible. Here is my code so far:

```
#Import Discord
import discord

#Client And Pemrs
client = discord.Client()

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
@client.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when,):
    if user.id == 574638576155754498: 
        general_channel = client.get_channel(784127484823339031)
        await kick(reason="He said the word") 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
#What The Bot Doing
  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):
   if "Valorant" in message.content:
        await message.author.kick(reason="He said the word") 
   if "valorant" in message.content:
        await message.author.kick(reason="He said the word") 
   if "VALORANT" in message.content:
        await message.author.kick(reason="He said the word") 

#Run The Client
client.run('token')
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You have to put your on message event outside the on_ready event. You also need to use user.kick() inside the on_typing event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't have events in events, so move `on_message` to outside of `on_ready`.
When you did this, the code should kick members when they say `Valorant`.
Then, in `on_typing`, simply add `user` before `kick(reason="He said the word")`, and before that, test if it is a member object:

```py
@client.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when,):
    if user.id == 574638576155754498: 
        general_channel = client.get_channel(784127484823339031)
        if isinstance(user, discord.Member): #when this is not true, the typing occured in a dm channel, where you can't kick.
            await user.kick(reason="He said the word")
```

So your final code would be:

```py
#Import Discord
import discord

#Client And Pemrs
client = discord.Client()

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when,):
    if user.id == 574638576155754498: 
        general_channel = client.get_channel(784127484823339031)
        if isinstance(user, discord.Member): #when this is not true, the typing occured in a dm channel, where you can't kick.
            await user.kick(reason="He said the word") 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Client is ready") #the on_ready function is called only when the client is ready, so we just print in there that the client is ready

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "valorant" in message.content.lower(): #use the changes dank tagg suggested
        await message.author.kick(reason="He said the word") 

#Run The Client
client.run('token')
```

---

References:

- [member.kick](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.kick)

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
   if "Valorant" in message.content:
        await message.author.kick(reason="He said the word") 
   if "valorant" in message.content:
        await message.author.kick(reason="He said the word") 
   if "VALORANT" in message.content:
        await message.author.kick(reason="He said the word")
```

Can be simplefied into

```
   if "valorant" in message.content.lower():
        await message.author.kick(reason="He said the word")
```

This should be a comment, but since it doesn't support Markdown i posted it as an answer